# How to load application.properties in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, properties, property-files

My spring application start's via WebApplicationInitializer.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

I have Config class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"))
})
public class MainConfig
{
  ....
}
```

And in application.properties file I try to override the spring and logging properties

```
logging.level.com.app=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

The file application.properties is in the directory src/main/resources

But it has no effect - means that no property is applied to the spring or logging system

Comment: What do you mean it has no effect? What do you expect?

Comment: With your `@Configuration`, `application.properties` becomes a property source. You haven't shown us anywhere where you're using those properties.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking. Why do you expect your property source to apply to "logging system"??

Comment: Why not ? In all examples this is written. In addition, the properties of the spring itself are also not applied

Comment: What examples? What do you mean by _properties of the spring itself_?

Answer (score -2):

Try using SpringBoot. In spring boot application.properties is read by default and you don't even need to use @PropertySource to read it. You can download a spring boot application skeleton from https://start.spring.io/